# Java code documentation in a separate docs file somehow mapped to a source file?

Tags: java, documentation, javadocs

What would be a good alternative to inline Java documentation, i.e. can one have a separate docs file somehow mapped to a java source file?

I have never liked huge comment sections littered in code.

Comment: why would you need this?

Comment: @gnat just personal preference, for a hobby project.

Comment: @downvotes looks like I've irritated the _religious_ coders :)

Comment: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." ([faq])

Comment: Kindly enlighten me about what in this question makes it impractical, unreal. I'll appreciate that too.

Comment: it would be great if your question explained what kind of problems you're having with standard javadoc. As currently phrased, it's hard to tell whether there is a problem at all, making attempts to answer the question kind of a [guessing game](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/)

Comment: The real problem with documenting code in a different file is that it is less likely to get updated. When a function changes, sometimes the documentation is not always updated to exactly match it. If the documentation is moved to a different file, there is now one extra step to making the correct change. It also make it less obvious that the documentation is wrong. You will only see it when you look specifically at the documentation, not when you scroll passed it in the code.

Comment: @unholysampler Thanks. So, its generally not a good Idea. I'just have never (personally) liked huge comment sections littered in code , so was just looking for options. You might like to transfer your comment to an answer.

Comment: @wingman: Still curious about your objection.  Do you dislike comment sections in general, or the useless comments that litter so many projects.

Comment: @kevincline comments sections may indeed be overwhelming, even when filled with really useful details. See for example [java.util.concurrent.Executor source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/Executor.java) in openjdk 6-b14

Comment: @kevincline Small sections are OK, but huge ones throw me off focus when I'm scrolling through the code. By huge ones I mean when I have to include a detailed paragraph, and a mini example.

Comment: Possibly related: how to fold/collapse comment blocks in your IDE, such as [Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21968768/how-to-fold-comments-in-eclipse).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have been using Javadoc feature of [package comments](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#packagecomments) to avoid littering source code with verbose documentation comments:

> #### Package-Level Comments
>
> With Javadoc 1.2, package-level doc comments are available. Each package can have its own package-level doc comment source file that The Javadoc tool will merge into the documentation that it produces. This file is named `package.html` (and is same name for all packages). This file is kept in the source directory along with all the `*.java` files. (Do not put the `packages.html` file in the new doc-files source directory, because those files are only copied to the destination and are not processed.)
>
> The file [package.html](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/package-142590.html) is an example of a package-level source file for `java.text` and [package-summary.html](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/package-summary-142451.html) is the file that the Javadoc tool generates.
>
> The Javadoc tool processes `package.html` by doing three things...

Using above feature, I had detailed verbose documentation for classes and methods in the package stored separately of code, in a dedicated html file. As for Javadoc comments in java files, I just wrote brief explanations there, adding text like

> If needed, refer to package documentation for more details.

One thing I particularly liked about this was that although docs were in the separate file and in a format more convenient for large docs (html), it has been stored close enough to related source code and all the updates in it were automatically picked up during the build.

---

Starting from **Java 1.5**, you can alternatively put a `package-info.java` along with the classes of the package. This file should look like this:

```
/**
 * Javadoc for your package here
 */
package com.yourpackage;
```

[JLS documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.4.1) suggests that this is preferred way:

> The following scheme is strongly recommended for file-system-based implementations: The sole annotated package declaration, if it exists, is placed in a source file called `package-info.java` in the directory containing the source files for the package...
>
> It is recommended that `package-info.java`, if it is present, take the place of `package.html` for javadoc and other similar documentation generation systems. If this file is present, the documentation generation tool should look for the package documentation comment immediately preceding the (possibly annotated) package declaration in package-info.java. In this way, `package-info.java` becomes the sole repository for package-level annotations and documentation. If, in future, it becomes desirable to add any other package-level information, this file should prove a convenient home for this information.

Comment: how do you find package-info.java from the perspective of actually writing the text, HTML tags, javadoc keywords etc? Is it clunky or is it not a problem?